# Slow downloading from own server

Tags: networking, freebsd, ftp, vps

I've a small VPS and I can download anything only with slow speed - only sometimes (and sometimes with normal speed). I can download from any other webpage (for example the FreeBSD's ISO files) with normal speed.
I can log into another server and I can download good speed from my VPS.
I tried from another machine at home (Linux Mint): very slow downloading again.

So I think the server has some settings for my home IP. Is it possible? How can I check it?

Maybe important: my laptop calls periodically (via `cron`) a php on my server and this php script saves the IP, a script writes it into `/etc/hosts` and can login to ssh only from this IP.

Comment: Check with tcpdump (on client and server). Possible problems include: DNS misconfiguration, broken IP(v6) configuration, Firewall issues etc.

Comment: Uhm. I'm very beginner in networking. How should call tcpdump in my case? I run 'fetch ftp://...' command and run `tcpdump port ftp` and see its output?

Comment: yes. i just now saw that you are using ftp, a first test would be to download something via http.

Comment: Okay. Now the http works fine. Should I run tcpdump and save its output? And when the speed will slow do it again?

Comment: So this looks like a Firewall problem then. Do you have a firewall running on the VPS? which ftp-client do you use? fetch(1)?

Comment: I'm using fail2ban on VPS with ipfw (`firewall_enable` is `yes` and `firewall_type` is `open` in rc.conf). I tried download with `fetch` - as you wrote.

Comment: Hm, fetch should already use passive mode, but still it might be useful to test disabling the firewall for a moment to check if it influences the download.Of course it could also be  a firewall anywhere on the way.

Comment: After `service ipfw stop` the downloading still slow (`fetch -p ...`). On my laptop I don't have firewall. (I asked this question on FreeBSD's forum too - if you're member maybe can continue on the forum)